# Custom sprite and glyphs not showing in Maputnik

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles

I'm completely new to vector tiles and mapbox. In order to test different icons, fills, etc. I found Maputnik would be the best option. Working with regular outlines, fills and other primitives is just fine but when it came to implementing custom icons and text labels I became confused.

Using spritezero-cli I created a custom sprite: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yaras-phoenix/test/master/sprite/test_sprite

And according to [this tutorial](https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-web/tutorials-advanced/creating-custom-glyphs) I created a simple onefont-fontstack: https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-web/tutorials-advanced/creating-custom-glyphs

I placed my links in Maputnik's Style Settings and expected to fill "Pattern" option to be activated and to see my font in text "Font" drop-down list but none of that happened.

Sprite's .json and .png files are fetched with code 200 but Maputnik seems to expect one more file I don't have. I see "GET https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yaras-phoenix/test/master/glyphs.json 404 (Not Found)" in Chrome DevTools. So I guess I need some extra json file.

Could anyone point me in some direction? I'm quite sure I do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

Seems that something in Maputnik is not working in version 1.6.1 because defining the icon I need in"fill-pattern" parameter made it work.

Then, the glyphs. I haven't found this information in Mapbox GL JS specs but I created a .json file with the list of fonts used in square brackets and placed it in the root folder. This made glyphs work.